# How to save statement input Angular?

Tags: angular, angular8

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items">
    <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.score }}</td>
    <td><input size="7" /></td>
</tr>
```

Where `items` in array of objects that is received from server each 5 seconds.

Problem is if fill inputs `<input size="7" />` it will be replaced after next rendering. How to save the statement of these inputs?

Comment: U suppose I need to use ngModel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular will *recreate* DOM elements when items in a collection are changed and rendered via `*ngFor`. By default, Angular will track how items are unique by using an `===` comparison on the values.

> Where items in array of objects that is received from server each 5 seconds.

Likely means, that the `items` array is a *new array* every 5 seconds. So each *item* is a *new item*, and `*ngFor` will recreate each DOM element.

You have to use a `trackby` to tell Angular to use the `item.id` as the unique identifier.

```html
<tr *ngFor="let item of items; trackby: trackItems">
    <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.score }}</td>
    <td><input size="7" /></td>
</tr>
```

Component:

```js
   const trackItems = (indx, item) => item.id;
```

Comment: Thank you, it is good remark, but I need to save input values and assign them to model

Comment: @OPV you can use any methods you like. `(changed)` or `[(ngModel]]` or `[formControl]`. This is covered in the forms section of the Angular documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
    <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.score }}</td>
    <td><input size="7" [(ngModel)]="item.value"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pnjcns?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

As per your comment, try like this:

Template:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items">
    <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.score }}</td>
    <td><input size="7"  (change)="onChange(item.id, $event.target.value)"/></td>
</tr>
```

TS:

```
  model = [];


  onChange(id,value) {
    this.model.push({id:id,value:value})
  }
```

Comment: I dont have item.value in initial object

Comment: Input is filled by user, manually, but all inputs values are overwrited after getting a new data from server

Comment: Check modified answer

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<table class="table table-sm">
    <tr *ngFor="let item of items;let index = index;trackBy:trackByIndex;">
        <td>{{item.id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.score}}</td>
        <td>
            <input [(ngModel)]="items[index].YourPropName">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

then in your component:

```
trackByIndex(index: number, obj: any): any {
  return index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use trackBy the prevent dom elemnts to being created every time ngFor is updated... you could also use another object to add the values every time you refresh your array...

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f1vpwt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
refreshItems(){
    // items receifved every 5 seconds..
    this.received = [
    {
      id:1,
      name: 'name: ',
      score: Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1  
    },
    {
      id:2,
      name: 'name2: ',
      score: Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1  
    }
    ];
    this.items = this.received.map(received => {
      return {
        ...received,
        value: this.items.find(item => item.id === received.id).value || '',
      }
    });
  }
```