# How to use ngModel in ngFor?

Tags: angular

Why this code is not working:

```
model:any = {};

<tr *ngFor="let item of items">
  <td><input [ngModel]="model[id]" size="7" /></td>
</tr>
```

It says there is no `id` inside `model`. How to use `ngModel` properly in `*ngFor`?

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58590578/how-to-save-statement-input-angular/58591115#58591115

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

TS:

```
model = [];
```

Template:

```
<input size="7"  (change)="model[item.id]=$event.target.value"/>
```